# Is it possible to execute a CallableStament on a different Connection?

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, connection-pooling, callable-statement

It is generally considered a good practice to reuse `CallableStatement`'s instances (check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html)).

But when creating a `CallableStatement`, that statement (from my understanding) is bound
to a specific `Connection`. So we usually do:

```
Connection con = pool.getConnection();
CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{ some stmt; }");
st.executeQuery();
st.close();
con.close();
```

From what I checked, the following is not going to execute the query:

```
Connection con = pool.getConnection();
CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{ some stmt; }");
con.close();
con = pool.getConnection(); // possibly another new connection, different than the one used to create the CallableStatement instance
st.executeQuery();
st.close();
```

My question is: if I want to reuse all my `CallableStatement` instances, but on the other hand still being able to get new connections and close the old ones **(not have always have the same connection open)** what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PreparedStatement`s are (or ought to be) cached by your JDBC driver.  See e.g. http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

This means you should not hold on to one and use between connections, but don't worry, your driver will manage caching for you.  Essentially what happens is each connection will cache its own, so if you have 5 connections, you'll have 5 cached copies lying around, which is probably sufficiently small.

Calling `prepareStatement` will retrieve from cache if cached and allocate if not. So repeated calls to `prepareStatement` are lightweight. This is the correct use of the API.

See e.g. [Oracle's docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/stmtcach.htm) which is technically Oracle-specific but I believe this information is standard.

Comment: so, this means that's it's OK to do a `prepareCall` every time before executing a query? I didn't fully understand your answer. They are cached and so, it's OK for me to call the same `prepareCall` multiple times?

Comment: @foobar IIRC, yes, that is correct.  Call `prepareCall` each time and JDBC will check and see if it's in its cache already.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question (will accept your answer in 5 minutes). Would be nice if you could enclose your comment answer inside your real answer. Thanks ;)